# PHP Array - Json Data - Generate table

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, html-table

I'm trying to generate a table with data from an php array.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php       
            $result = array();
            ob_start();

            include 'include/podcastRead.php';

            $result = ob_get_clean();
 ?>
```

HTML table:

```
    <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table" id="tablee">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Nome</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Nerdcast</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
```

The $result array have json data, here it is:

```
{"podcast":[{"id":"1","nome":"Dan Carlin is Hardcore History"},{"id":"2","nome":"Dose Extra"}]}
```

I have tried many ways, read and re-read so much posts here and other sites.
I can't create a table.

I have also tried some plugins like [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/).

It appears to be simple. lol.

How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `json_decode()` the `$result` you will get an object, so you then run a foreach loop on the `$data->podcast` and output a table for each row.

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($result);
echo '<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table" id="tablee">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Nome</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
foreach ($data->podcast as $row) {
    echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">'.$row->nome.'</td>
    </tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>
</table>';
?>
```

Comment: I was sure it was not difficult. But I wasn't successful. It worked. Thank you @Tristan.